# Add HTML before end tag in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to add HTML using jQuery between

`</font>` and `</td>`

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>something</span>
            <font color="#C40404">*</font>
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please specify the javascript of the above question, that would make people understand the problem more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it using different ways.

1. [`append();`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

   ```
   $('table tr:first td:first').append('<span>Text</span>');
   ```
2. [`after();`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

   ```
   $('table tr:first td:first font').after('<span>Text</span>');
   ```
3. [`appendTo();`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

   ```
   $('<span>Text 3</span>').appendTo($('table tr:first td:first'));
   ```

**DEMO**

```js
$('table tr:first td:first').append('<span>Text 1</span>');
$('table tr:first td:first font').after('<span> Text 2</span>');
$('<span>Text 3</span>').appendTo($('table tr:first td:first'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>something</span>
            <font color="#C40404">*</font>
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the HTML what u want to update:

Unfortunately append only works reliably within the DOM.
Hope it helps:

`$('table tr:first td').append("something");`

Answer (score 3):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id='td1'>
            <span>something</span>
            <font color="#C40404">*</font>
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>

<script>

$('#td1').append("whatever you want here");

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

To append all `td` in the table

```
var html = '<div>...</div>';
$('table td').append(html);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you simply could use the [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) jQuery method to do this, targeting your td.

Something like `$('td').append('your html go here.');`.

Depending on what you really want, you can use the css ::after pseudo element, but it's not really an answer to your question, just another way to do that.